# Design of an xml reader

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class XmlReader that reads a xml and a class Point that represents a point. A point can have various types, the different types are described by an enum inside the class Point.

```
class XmlReader {

    void read()
    {
        string typeReadFromXML;
        vector<double> coordinates;
        Point* pt = newPoint(typeReadFromXML, coordinates);

        // OR
        //string typeReadFromXML;
        //PointType type= XMLReader::conversion(typeReadFromXML);
        //vector<double> coordinates;
        //Point* pt = newPoint(type, coordinates);
    }
};

class Point {

    Point(string type, vector<double> v)
    {
        _type = conversion(type);
    }

    Point(PointType type, vector<double> v)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

private:
    enum PointType {
        type1,
        type2
    };

    PointType conversion(string){}

    PointType _type;
    vector<double> _coords;
};
```

Is it ok to do the conversion from a string to my custom type in the Point class or is it preferable to do this conversion in the read method of the XmlReader class ?

The problem with converting a string to a PointType in the Point Class is that if
I change the keywords of my xml format, I will also have to change the Point Class ( ie the conversion method). What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it is best practice to design modules and components in the most orthogonal way possible.

In this case, it means that a Point class that is cleanly encapsulated and not aware of, or dependent on the underlying XML format, can be *reused* for other purposes: different XML format, JSON, any other sources. It also makes it easier to understand for somebody *reading* the code, and easier to *maintain*.

This way, you get a three-level architecture: XML format > conversion > Point class.

There are exceptions to any rules, of course, and in general, if there are other goals than code reuse, readability and maintenance (such as, if performance is critical), it can justify reducing the number of levels in the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Format class to communicate between Point and XMLReader.

```
static PointType conversion(string typ, const Format& format)
{ if (format.is...()) 
    return (typ == "...") ? ... : ...;
  ...
}
```

could decide the adequate type depending on the format.

Then if you decide to have derivate classes from Point, for example CrossPoint, BulletPoint, the static keyword can help to create the right point depending on typeReadFromXML.